# Get child class of argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a method which gets a parent class as an argument.
I need to know at compile time what is the child class of that argument.

```
class A{
...
};

class B: public A{
...
};

class C: public A{
...
};

void foo(A a){
    //is a specialized in B or C?
}

C c;
foo(c); //here it is C
```

Comment: Explain why you think you need to know this. In fact, in foo() it will always be an object of type A, because of slicing.

Comment: With `foo` as you show it, taking an `A` object by value, it is *neither* `B` nor `C`.

Comment: You should have 2 `foo` functions: `void foo(B b){}` and `void foo(C c){}`

Comment: And the way to solve whatever problem you have is either through overloading, or through virtual functions and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind your expectation is a kind of compile time polymorphism....

You can achieve it by function overloading.

There is no wrong in writing two different functions (as DimChtz in comments said)....one with argument for type B and another with argument for type C.